# how to share "build repository dir" between jobs in multiple gitlab runner configuration?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using a gitlab runner to deploy application
-shared gitlab runner and concurrent count is 4

```
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
        concurrent = 4
        check_interval = 0
        executor = shell
```

All jobs run in a different stage each other.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build-prod-stage
  - deploy-prod-stage

BUILD_PROD_JOB:
  stage: build-prod-stage
  variables:    
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none      
  script:
    - xxxxxx
    - xxxxx

DEPLOY_PROD_JOB:
  variables:
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none 
  stage: deploy-prod-stage
  script: 
    - xxxxxx
    - xxxxxx*
```

Mostly, BUILD_PROD_JOB and DEPLOY_PROD_JOB run in a same build directory.
But, sometimes they use a different directory each other

***gitlab-runner log***

**BUILD_PROD_JOB**
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /xxxx/gitlab-runner/builds/(gitlab-runner name)/**1**/(respository name)/.git/
.....

**DEPLOY_PROD_JOB**
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /xxxx/gitlab-runner/builds/(gitlab-runner name)/**0**/(respository name)/.git/
....

I guessed why this things happen.

- BUILD_PROD_JOB started to run while other job is running. so, CI_CONCURRENT_ID is 1
- DEPLOY_PROD_JOB started to run after other jobs is completed, so CI_CONCURRENT_ID is 0

In this case, can I force "DEPLO_PROD_JOB" runs in same build_dir of "BUILD_PROD_JOB"?

- BUILD_PRODJOB --> /xxxx/gitlab-runner/builds/(gitlab-runner name)/**1**/(respository name)/.git/
- DEPLOY_PRODJOB --> /xxxx/gitlab-runner/builds/(gitlab-runner name)/**1**/(respository name)/.git/

In this case, can I force "DEPLO_PROD_JOB" runs in same build_dir of "BUILD_PROD_JOB"?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your jobs depend on each other, e. g. `DEPLOY_PROD_JOB` needs files created in `BUILD_PROD_JOB`. Instead of forcing the GitLab Runner to use the same directory for the jobs, you should try using the [`artifacts` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) to pass files from one job to another. This way the solution is independent from the host machine of the GitLab Runner.

```
stages:
  - build-prod-stage
  - deploy-prod-stage 

BUILD_PROD_JOB:
  stage: build-prod-stage
  variables:
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
  script:
    - xxxx
    - xxxx
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - myBuildFiles/*
  
  DEPLOY_PROD_JOB:
    stage: deploy-prod-stage
    variables:
      GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
    script:
      - xxxx
      # "myBuildFiles/" is now available here
      - xxxx
```

Be aware that a wildcard in the top-level directory, like

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - *
```

will also archive the `.git` directory, which can cause weird behaviour.